# "The execution context was destroyed, most likely due to a navigation" when scraping with Puppeteer in NextJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, next.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to create an application to search for my music on some sites that post illegal content so I can ask them to delete it later.

I am facing this problem in puppeteer, when I try to press enter on the search input I get this error: `Error: Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation.`

I have two files. One called urlScrapper.js with my script and an array with the names of my songs:

```
import InfringementFinder from './InfringementFinder.js';

const songs = ['Artist Name - Song Name', 'Artist Name - Song Name'];
const irscCodes = ['XXXXXXXXXX', XXXXXXXXXX];

InfringementFinder(songs, irscCodes).then(() => {
  console.log('Search complete!');
}).catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

and InfringementFinder.js:

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';


const InfringementFinder = async (songs, irscCodes) => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  
  const mainPage = 'https://example.com/';
  await page.goto(mainPage);
  
  // This enter the search term in the input field
  await page.type('.search-field', 'Artist Name - Song Name'); // this supposed to be my prop but someone doesnt work

  // Trigger the search by submitting the form
  const searchSubmit = await page.waitForSelector('.search-submit');
  await searchSubmit.press('Enter');

  // Wait for the search results to load
  await page.waitForSelector('.g1-frame');
  
  // This finds the first entry-content element containing the information
  const entryContent = await page.$('.g1-frame');
  if (!entryContent) return;
  
  // This press on the element
  await entryContent.press('Enter');

  // Extract the relevant information
  try {
    const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
      const trackElements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('li', 'ol', 'a', 'href', 'strong', 'span', 'p', 'div', 'class'))
      .filter(el => el.innerText.includes('Artist Name - Song Name'));
      const tracks = trackElements.map(trackElement => {
        const trackName = trackElement.innerText.split(' – ')[0];
        return { trackName };
      });
      const downloadLinks = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.dl-btn'))
        .map(link => link.getAttribute('href'));
    
      return { tracks, downloadLinks };
    });
    
    console.log('Data:', data); 
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  } finally {
    await browser.close();
  }
};

export default InfringementFinder;
```

It only works if I try to scrape a page where I know my music is posted and using a different code version but the idea is to search the whole website using the search input.

The logic is as follows: You click on the search input, type the name of the song, navigate to another page, click on your music, navigate to another page, and scrape the name of the songs and links to illegal downloads.

Comment: Are you able to share the page? Often, you can build the URL of the search results page without having to use the input box and press enter. You could maybe click that button. You could also try `await Promise.all([page.waitForNavigation(), searchSubmit.press("Enter")])`

Comment: @ggorlen added: ```await Promise.all([page.waitForNavigation({ timeout: 60000 }), searchSubmit.press("Enter")]);``` and I get: ```TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 60000 ms exceeded```

Comment: At the time of writing, and I'm not a lawyer and this is not legal advice, but web scraping is legal in the US. Usually a TOS violation. I can understand wanting to keep the page private though, so I won't post it in the answer. Without the page, it's like asking me to hit a target with a blindfold on. Sometimes it's possible to make a minimal example of a page without the actual page, but most pages are too complex and people tend to be too lazy to bother.

Comment: @ggorlen yes that's the way it works, not this particular code but another one I created for a specific page but the idea is to be able to do it with the main domain and search the website without having to do it manually. The problem is that Aphex Twin may have releases on several labels, so I need to delete only the Aphex Twin albums (I wish) on my label.

Comment: So you're using `irscCodes` as the search term? I'm not sure what we're searching for but if you can show an example, that makes it easier to write an answer that works for you.

Comment: @ggorlen the irscCodes are not really necessary because they are not displayed on the page. I would appreciate though if once you would be able to help me if you could remove the link to the website, even though it is a Russian illegal download site I prefer not to promote it.

Comment: All right, I have the link now and deleted my comment with it, but I still can't really answer until I'm clear what we're searching for and what the final output is supposed to be. Thanks. I'll repost two things I said in the deleted comment:  `querySelectorAll` only accepts 1 argument and it's usually better to directly navigate to the search results page by building the URL rather than messing with DOM inputs and navigations.

Comment: @ggorlen if you go on that site, you can pick a random release, and then try to scrape by artist name and song name, if it works you will get the name of songs plus links to download, usually 3 links.

Comment: Ah, I see. Makes sense. I'll add an answer when I get time this afternoon.

Comment: @ggorlen Thank you very much, I really appreciate it, this is hunting me.

Comment: Outstanding answer and very well explained. Thank you very much @ggorlen . Cheerio rocks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is probably due to the following code:

```js
await entryContent.press('Enter'); // triggers a nav

  // Extract the relevant information immediately
  // without waiting for nav to complete
  try {
    const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
```

I'd either wait for a nav here or wait for the selector on the next page you're about to access with `evaluate`.

Also,

```js
document.querySelectorAll('li', 'ol', 'a', 'href', 'strong', 'span', 'p', 'div', 'class')
```

doesn't make sense: `querySelectorAll` only accepts one parameter, and `'class'` isn't a name of an HTML element. It's a good idea to test this in the browser first, because it's plain JS.

I don't see `'Artist Name - Song Name'` anywhere on the page.

This code:

```js
await page.waitForSelector('.g1-frame');
  
// This finds the first entry-content element containing the information
const entryContent = await page.$('.g1-frame');
if (!entryContent) return;
```

could [just be](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#not-using-the-return-value-of-waitforselector-and-waitforxpath):

```js
const entryContent = await page.waitForSelector('.g1-frame');
```

---

It's common to assume you need to navigate the site as the user would: go to the homepage, type in the search term, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>...

Better is to look at the query string of the search page and build your own, avoiding the extra nav and fuss of dealing with the DOM. Here's an example:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^19.6.3

const baseUrl = "<Your base URL, ending in .net>";
const searchTerm = "autechre";

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const url = `${baseUrl}?s=${encodeURIComponent(searchTerm)}`;
  await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  page.on("request", request => {
    if (request.resourceType() === "document") {
      request.continue();
    }
    else {
      request.abort();
    }
  });
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  await (await page.$(".g1-frame")).click();
  const trackListEl = await page.waitForSelector(".entry-content > .greyf12");
  const tracks = await trackListEl.$$eval("li", els => {
    const fields = ["artist", "track"];
    return els.map(e =>
      Object.fromEntries(
        e.textContent
          .split(/ *– */)
          .map((e, i) => [fields[i], e.trim()]),
      )
    );
  });
  const downloadLinks = await page.$$eval(".dl-btn", els =>
    els.map(e => e.getAttribute("href"))
  );
  console.log({tracks, downloadLinks});
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Note that we don't need to execute JS and we're blocking almost all resource requests, so we can speed up the scrape significantly by [switching to fetch/axios and a simple HTML parser like Cheerio](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#using-puppeteer-when-other-tools-are-more-appropriate):

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // 1.0.0-rc.12

const baseUrl = "<Your base URL, ending in .net>";
const searchTerm = "autechre";
const url = `${baseUrl}?s=${encodeURIComponent(searchTerm)}`;

const get = url =>
  fetch(url) // Node 18 or install node-fetch, or use another library like axios
    .then(res => {
      if (!res.ok) {
        throw Error(res.statusText);
      }

      return res.text();
    });

get(url)
  .then(html =>
    get(cheerio.load(html)(".entry-title a").attr("href"))
  )
  .then(html => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    const tracks = [...$(".entry-content > .greyf12 li")].map(
      e => {
        const fields = ["artist", "track"];
        return Object.fromEntries(
          $(e)
            .text()
            .split(/ *– */)
            .map((e, i) => [fields[i], e.trim()])
        );
      }
    );
    const downloadLinks = [...$(".dl-btn")].map(e =>
      $(e).attr("href")
    );
    console.log({tracks, downloadLinks});
  });
```

The code is simpler, and on my machine, twice as fast as Puppeteer.